# Sharepoint 2013 Variations Automation

Tags: 2013, variations

I'm able to use http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-provisioning-variations-in-sharepoint-server-2010/ link to automate variations setup SP 2013 via Powershell. One think I'm not able to figure out is, how to setup the Target Label Behavior to "Automatically Update". I've searched through the VariationsList Items properties to see if I can find any item which describes how to turn this on, but no luck. From what I read SP supposed to setup all variations to automatically update from source. Anybody ideas how to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `UpdateWebPartsPropertyName` property of `_VarRelationshipsListId` to true, for all the target variations to automatically update from source.

```
    $guid = [Guid]$rootWeb.GetProperty("_VarRelationshipsListId");
    $list = $rootWeb.Lists[$guid];    
    $rootFolder = $list.RootFolder;          
    $list.RootFolder.Properties["UpdateWebPartsPropertyName"] = $true;
```

[image]